# PubNub Push Notification sends incorrect data on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pubnub

Let me go straight to the point, with Firebase Cloud Messaging and Android Oreo there have been some major changes when it comes to using their APIs.

I have entered my Firebase Server Api Key in the PubNub Console, push notification works absolutely fine on the Firebase console, but when publishing notification with PubNub, remoteMessage.toString gives => `com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage@ffe9xxx` in the OnMessageReceived function.

I am publishing something like this

```
JsonObject payload = new JsonObject();

        JsonObject androidData = new JsonObject();
        androidData.addProperty("contentText","test content");
        androidData.addProperty("contentTitle","Title");

        JsonObject notification = new JsonObject();
        notification.add("notification",androidData);


        JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
        data.add("data", notification);
        payload.add("pn_gcm", data);
```

in

```
PubNubObject.publish()
            .message(payload)
             etc..
```

Any idea why is this happening?
Thank you in advance.

**Code on the receiving end**

There is a class which extends FirebaseMessagingService, codes for `OnMessageReceived` function:

```
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
    //for testing firebase notification
    Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification 
    Body:"+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());  
 } else {
    //for anything else, I wanted to see what was coming from the server
    //this is where I am getting the message when using PubNub notification
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: remoteMessage to 
    str:"+remoteMessage.toString() );
 }
```

Comment: What does your code look like on the message receive side?

Comment: @CraigConover thanks for replying, I have updated the post with the piece of code you requested

Comment: I believe what is happening is that you are embedding the `notification` key/value inside of the `data` key and you might just need to use the API, `remoteMessage.getData() ` instead of `remoteMessage.getNotification()`. If `notification` key was at the top level, it might work. See [Android docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive). Do let me know if that work.

Comment: I believe you contacted our support directly. If so, whatever we resolve there will be posted back here as the answer.

Comment: The problem was indeed with the remoteMessage.getNotification(), it should have been remoteMessage.getData(). Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Android `getData` vs `getNotification` API

You are nesting the `notification` key/value inside of the `data` key and just need to use the API, `remoteMessage.getData()` instead of `remoteMessage.getNotification()`.

If `notification` key was at the top level, it would work. [See Android docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

Instead of this:

```
{
 "pn_gcm": {
  "data": {
   "notification": {
    "contentText": "test content",
    "contentTitle": "Title"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This if switing to `remoteMessage.getData()`:

```
{
 "pn_gcm": {
  "data": {
    "contentText": "test content",
    "contentTitle": "Title"
  }
 }
}
```

Or this if sticking with `remoteMessage.getNotification()`:

```
{
 "pn_gcm": {
  "notification": {
    "contentText": "test content",
    "contentTitle": "Title"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

PubNub basically just looks for the `pn_gcm` in the message payload when it is published and grabs whatever is inside of it and passes that directly to Google's FCM service for the devices that are registered (with PubNub) for that channel to receive GCM (FCM).

If the data is not formatted properly we would receive an error back from FCM which should be reported on the channel's `-pndebug` channel (assuming `pn_debug:true` was included in the published message payload).

For full details on troubleshooting FCM (GCM) or APONS issues with PubNub, please review [How can I troubleshoot my push notification issues?](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043605-how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues-)